# Caliburn Micro with WPF MouseBinding

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, inputbinding

I would like to capture a mouse click on a WPF `<Rectangle>` and route it to a command implementation using Caliburn Micro. Here is the markup:

```
<Rectangle ... >
    <Rectangle.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" />
    </Rectangle.InputBindings>
</Rectangle>
```

What Caliburn Micro syntax do I need to add to the `<MouseBinding>` element so that I can route the click to my view model?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to just bind the `Command` to a command property in your VM?

Comment: Well, with Caliburn Micro, there is no such thing as ICommand. Its philosophy is that ICommand isn't needed. I am looking to see if I can find a solution that stays within the overall Caliburn Micro philosophy.

Comment: I cannot think of any good reason why anyone would do that. What reasons are given?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a standard `Button` control, and change the control template to display a rectangle:

```
<Button x:Name="Submit">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle ... />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have wrote small markup extension which behaves very similar to Caliburn.Micro actions. It calls method on view model. This example supports only methods without parameters, but could be easily extended.

Usage:

```
    <Border.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="{ns:CallViemodelMethod SomeMethod}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
    </Border.InputBindings>
```

View model:

```
public class SomeViewModel 
{
    publiv void SomeMethod()
    {
        // handle click
    }
}
```

Extension:

```
public class CallViemodelMethod : MarkupExtension, ICommand
{
    private readonly string _methodName;
    private FrameworkElement _rootObject;

    public CallViemodelMethod(string methodName)
    {
        _methodName = methodName;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // get root of target page
        var provideRoot = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IRootObjectProvider)) as IRootObjectProvider;
        _rootObject = provideRoot?.RootObject as FrameworkElement;
        return this;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var dataContext = _rootObject?.DataContext;
        if (dataContext == null) return;

        var methodInfo = dataContext.GetType().GetMethod(_methodName);
        if (methodInfo == null) return;

        methodInfo.Invoke(dataContext, new object[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to get the LeftClick is just give a name to the rectangle and make a method with the same name in the viewmodel of the view:
this is the real power of caliburn micro, which is convention over configuration ie naming conventions connecting view and viewmodel , command and response and so on ...

the xaml looks like

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle" >
</Rectangle>
```

and the viewmodel looks like

```
 public void Rectangle()
 { 
        // your code goes here
 }
```